# Error: Permission denied to access property 'SP' - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am using the the content editor webpart to display some data from a list.
I am using the approach of using a txt file in a content editor webpart.
When I edit the content editor I can see the content but when I save I don't see anything (blank)

I am also using IE 11. Could this be the issue?

Looking at the console I can see:

> Error: Permission denied to access property 'SP'

this is the SP services I am referencing to

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.01/jquery.SPServices.min.js
```

### Edited Question: (The below is whats in the txt file)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.01/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://XXX.sharepoint.com/SiteAssets/Scripts/jquery.quovolver.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="StyleSheet" href="https://XXX.sharepoint.com/SiteAssets/Scripts/quotes.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://XXX.sharepoint.com/SiteAssets/Scripts/quotes.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the content you are placing in the content editor?

Comment: Download the jQuery and SPService js files and upload it into SiteAssets. Also I see only references and no code?

Comment: Please post your entire code.